# How to get one item and do something specifically in a for loop in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

This is the code:

```
ls = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']


for z in ls:
    x = input("Do you like %s ?" %z)
    if x == 'yes':
        print('Cool, ' + z + ' is very good.')
        break
    elif x == 'no':   
        continue
    else:
        print('I am not sure what you want')
```

With this code, there are two things i'd like to do:

1 - after it loops by the second time (Do you like banana?) i'd like to print a message. But ONLY after the 'do you like banana' and not on the other times it loops. 
So is there a way to print a message only for one of the loops? Because if i try like this:

```
elif x == 'n':   
    print('are you sure you do not like it?')
    continue
```

it will print the message for all the 3 items in the list (apple, banana and pear).

2 - The other thing is to set that when the else statement runs (the user inputs something different from 'yes' or 'no') , i'd like it to restart in the beginning of the loop (ask the user again 'Do you like apple?' instead of continue to the second item ('Do you like banana').
Is there a way to set the loop to go back to the beginning?

Hope the questions are clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to want a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
ls = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']
i = 0
flag = True
while i<len(ls) :

    x = input("Do you like %s ?" %ls[i])
    if x == 'yes':
        print('Cool, ' + ls[i] + ' is very good.')
        flag = True
        break

    elif x == 'no':   
        if i >=1 and flag:
            print('are you sure you do not like it?')
            i = i -1
            flag = False
    else:
        i = -1
        flag = True
    i+=1
```

output:

1.

```
Do you like apple ?no
Do you like banana ?no
are you sure you do not like it?
Do you like banana ?no
Do you like pear ?no
```

2.

```
Do you like apple ?yes
Cool, apple is very good.
```

3.

```
Do you like apple ?no
Do you like banana ?yes
Cool, banana is very good.
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay for you I did it with enumerate and a flag:

```py
while True:
    successful_flag = True
    for i, z in enumerate(ls): 
        x = input("Do you like %s ?" %z) 
        if x == 'yes': 
            print('Cool, ' + z + ' is very good.') 
        elif x == 'no': 
            if i == 1: 
                print('Are you sure you do not like it?')    
        else: 
            print('I am not sure what you want') 
            successful_flag = False
            break 
    if successful_flag:
        break
```

Output:

`Do you like apple ?yes
Cool, apple is very good.
Do you like banana ?no
Are you sure you do not like it?
Do you like pear ?get out
I am not sure what you want
Do you like apple ?`

Answer (score 0):

## What is called a "state machine" would describe your problem quite well

[image: placeholder text for image]

## Each circle/square in the diagram is a "state." The user's input controls transitions between states

## CODE:

```
class YesNoStateBase:
    pass

class ExitState(YesNoStateBase):
    def ask_for_instructions(self):
        return ""

    def ask_for_data(self):
        return str(self)

    def ask_for_geography(self, *args):
        return self
ExitState.ExitState = ExitState

class YesNoState:

    def __init__(self, prompt, *, yes=ExitState, no=ExitState):
        self._prompt = prompt + " "
        self._yes = yes
        self._no = no

    def set_yes(self, state):
        self._yes = state

    def ask_for_instructions(self):
        return self._prompt

    def ask_for_data(self):
        return self._data

    def ask_for_geography(self, x_stryng):
        i_stryng = str(x_stryng).strip().lower()
        nxt_state = type(self).ExitState
        if i_stryng == "y" or i_stryng == "yes":
            self._data = self._prompt + " yes"
            nxt_state = self._yes
        elif i_stryng == "n" or i_stryng == "no":
            self._data = self._prompt + " no"
            nxt_state = self._no
        else:
            nxt_state = YesNoState(
                "I don't understand. Please try again\n" + self._prompt,
                yes=self._yes,
                no=self._no
            )
        return nxt_state

YesNoState.YesNoState = YesNoState
YesNoState.ExitState = ExitState

class StateMiner:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = list()
    def go_to_work(self, state):
        while True:
            # `msg`............`message`
            msg = state.ask_for_instructions()
            nxt_state = state.ask_for_geography(input(msg))
            datum = state.ask_for_data()
            self._data.append(datum)
            if nxt_state== state.ExitState:
                return
            state = nxt_state



GoAgainQ    = YesNoState("Do you want to play again? ")
PearQ       = YesNoState("Do you like pears? ", yes=GoAgainQ, no=GoAgainQ)
SureBananaQ = YesNoState("Are you certain that you do not like bananas (yes = hate bananas)?", yes=PearQ, no=PearQ)
BananaQ     = YesNoState("Do you like bananas? ", yes=PearQ, no=SureBananaQ)
AppleQ      = YesNoState("Do you like apples? ", yes=BananaQ, no=BananaQ)
GoAgainQ.set_yes(AppleQ )

bob = StateMiner()
bob.go_to_work(AppleQ)
print(40*"#", "RESULTS:", 40*"-", sep="\n")
print("\n".join(bob._data))
print(40*"-", sep="\n")
```

Example output:

```
########################################
RESULTS:
----------------------------------------
Do you like apples?   yes
Do you like bananas?   yes
Do you like pears?   yes
Do you want to play again?   yes
Do you like apples?   yes
Do you like bananas?   yes
Do you like pears?   yes
Do you want to play again?   no
----------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```